# Blender animation incorrect rotation of arms

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender, game-development

I've created a very simple humanoid in Blender and defined 5 animation actions. They all look good in Blender, but for some reason after importing the FBX file in Unity the arms are set incorrectly.

This is my Idle animation in Blender:
[image: Blender]

And this is how it shows up in Unity:
[image]

As you can see the right arm is rotated incorrectly and this problem applies to 3 out of 5 actions I have.
All the actions have an initial and final keyframe for every bone, to make sure they get reset when the animation cycles or switches.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging for few days and searching for an answer, I stumbled upon this Unity question https://answers.unity.com/questions/944333/animations-from-blender-going-super-weird.html which partially solved my problem.

Instead of exporting every animation I decided to push the ones I was interested in exporting to the NLA editor and select these settings in the Export menu when exporting the FBX:

- NLA Strips: to export all the NLA strips I pushed to the stack
- Key All Bones: to make sure a channel is automatically created before exporting for every bones (even the ones that didn't have an animation in an action)
- Force Start/End Keying: to add a keyframe to both start and end of the animation

These steps seem to have solved my problem.
These are my export settings:

[image]